# ForwardsBackwards running of a gif in Export

Tags: export, gif-format

I'm trying to export a gif from a list of images

The AnimationRepetitions command works, but the AnimationDirection does not. It just goes one way. Is there a way to loop back and forth?

Here's some example code:

```
list = Table[Plot[Exp[-A*x^2], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All], {A, .01, 1, .0495}];

Export["data.gif", list, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity,AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]
```

It only goes forward.

Is there a way to animate this forward and backward without invoking Animate? I'd like to keep the frame out of the way.

Comment: You can use `Animate` but also include `"ControlAppearance" -> None` as an `Export` option which will hide the controls. E.g.: `Export["~/Desktop/data.gif", ListAnimate[list, AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward], AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity, "ControlAppearance" -> None]`

Comment: @b2m2a1 That is probably worth an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Turning the comment to an answer. You can use `Animate` but also include `"ControlAppearance" -> None` as an `Export` option which will hide the controls. E.g.:

```
Export["~/Desktop/data.gif", ListAnimate[list, AnimationDirection -> 
  ForwardBackward], AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity, "ControlAppearance" -> None]
```